# Access is denied. Unable to open the service 'Tomcat5'

Tags: windows, tomcat, service, windows-services, tomcat5

I'm not sure what's happening here.  I have Tomcat5.5.26 installed on a Windows2008 Server.  The service works fine and starts automatically.  However, when I log into the system, I get a dialog box saying "Access is denied.  Unable to open the service 'Tomcat5'.  There are no issues with the service (afaik) and I can view it just fine through services.msc.  In fact, I've verified that I can change the logon credentials of the service and its start-up type.

I've tried searching the Windows Event Logs for this error, but can't find it.  Any idea why it's popping up?

The account I'm logging in as has Administrator Privileges, though interestingly when I try to run Tomcat5w.exe, unless I explicitly right-click and choose 'Run as Administrator' I'm not able to open it.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the last statement I included about permissions was the key.  It's still not clear to me why I get the error on startup, since my account has sys admin privileges, but...

... **to make the error go away** I had to right-click on the tomcat5w.exe file (\bin\tomcat5w.exe) > properties > compatibility tab.  Under sub-section 'Privilege Level' check off 'Run this program as an administrator'.